# Can Ubuntu run from usb drive?

Tags: 13.04, live-usb

I currently am a windows 7 user, but I'm interested in trying out Ubuntu. How can I download it on USB without installing it on my computer's hard drive?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create a USB stick that will load Ubuntu when plugged to your computer during boot. Detailed instructions about it are here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

If you also would like to experience the installation procedure I would suggest installing it virtually using for instance Virtualbox (which is free).

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple options to try out Ubuntu without installing it on your hard-drive.

1. You can use a USB drive or other and run a "live-cd" from there http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows
2. You can burn a CD or DVD of the ubuntu installer and actually install the operating system onto a usb drive
3. You can run something like VMWare Player or Virtualbox and set-up a VM to try out ubuntu while in your current operating system.